# Javascript .find using one element to return another

Tags: javascript

I am a student. I'm trying to return one element based on one other. I need to use .find to search for the result "W" (the year a sports team won) and return the corresponding year. I'm expected to write `function (superbowlWin(record)` in order to satisfy this.

```
const record = [
{ year: "1971", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1970", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1969", result: "W"},
{ year: "1968", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1967", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1966", result: "L"},
{ year: "1965", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1964", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1963", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1962", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1961", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1960", result: "N/A"}
]
```

Comment: also see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

The array method filter and find make a good job for this task. Both you will find below:

```js
const record = [
{ year: "1971", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1970", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1969", result: "W"},
{ year: "1968", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1967", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1966", result: "L"},
{ year: "1965", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1964", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1963", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1962", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1961", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1960", result: "N/A"}
]

let r = [];
r1 = record.filter(x => x.result === 'W');
console.log('result filter: ',r1)
r2 = record.find(x => x.result === 'W');
console.log('result find: ',r2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding JSFiddle for ref https://jsfiddle.net/ug70xL4y/

```
const record = [{ year: "1971", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1970", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1969", result: "W"},
{ year: "1968", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1967", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1966", result: "L"},
{ year: "1965", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1964", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1963", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1962", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1961", result: "N/A"},
{ year: "1960", result: "N/A"}];

function superbowlWin(records) {
let el = records.find(e=>e.result==='W');
if(el){
return el.year;
}else{
return undefined;
}
}
superbowlWin(record);
```